# Getting length of all elements that contain some class and they are before div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some div that has 4 other div's but those are like 2 rows with 2 columns:

Here is a picture because code it a little too long to be added as snippet.
[image: picture]

```
if(part.prev().hasClass("d") && part.prev().hasClass('d').length==1 && part.next().hasClass('d').length==0){
  part.prev().addClass('s').removeClass('d');
  part.remove();
}else{
  part.next().addClass('s').removeClass('d');
  part.remove();    
}
```

part - is some div
I use `prev()` to see does elements before div have class "d" or not and `next()` to check does elements after div have class "d" or not.

And by `part.prev().hasClass('d').length` I am trying to get the length of all elements before div so I can say if there is one element before doing something, if 2 do something else etc...

Comment: It would be much more effective to show us the code. An image of its result is almost useless in this case

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: `.hasClass()` returns boolean, and booleans do not have `.length` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** even simpler than mine example from the OP comment under the answer, using [jQuery `.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method:

```
part.prevAll('.d').length
```

---

**Original answer:**

To get an amount of preceding siblings with the expected class (`.d`), use [jQuery filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function) in which you check if the index is lower than the one of desired element (clicked in my example, to simplify):

```js
$(".d").on("click", function(event) {

  var index = $(this).index();
  var count = $(this).siblings(".d").filter(function(i, element) {
        return $(element).index() < index;
  }).length;
  
  console.log(count);
  
});
```

```css
#setup div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#setup div:hover { 
  background: green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="setup">
  <div class="d">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="d">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div class="d">5</div>
  <div class="d">6</div>
  <div class="d">7</div>
  <div class="d">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found different solution using part.prevAll('.d').length;

Comment: I didn't know this one, it's definitely better than mine, good job :).